# Stuck in proving a tautology using algebraic propositions.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have to prove p v ¬(p ∧ q) is a tautology using the algebraic propositions.

Here is how I tried to do, but incomplete.

> **Q.** p v ¬(p ∧ q)

(p v ¬p) ∧ (p v ¬q) **using Distributive Law**

T ∧ (p v ¬q) **using Complement Law**

?

Here I'm stuck.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first step isn't quite right:
\begin{align*}
p \lor \neg (p \land q)
&\equiv p \lor (\neg p \lor \neg q) &\text{by DeMorgan's Law} \\
&\equiv (p \lor \neg p) \lor \neg q &\text{by Associative Law} \\
&\equiv \top \lor \neg q &\text{by Inverse Law} \\
&\equiv \top &\text{by Domination Law}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have any cool trick, which helps you to see which rule to apply and avoid starting with wrong rules?

Comment: It's not so much about cool tricks as it is about chunking, filtering and also opportunistic pattern matching, all of which just come from experience. For example when you see something like ¬(p ∧ q), with experience you will mentally just apply DeMorgan's, and then you see that you have a bunch of ors, and you just mentally filter out the parentheses, knowing that they don't matter. Then you see that you have p∨¬p ∨..., which allows you to immediately ignore everything in the ... part.

Comment: There are some useful heuristics that you learn at first, like just automatically breaking off all the pieces of a conjunction, but after you've done it a while you don't do this anymore because you know that they're always there if you need them.